# Ubuntu, VirtualBox, RemixOS - endless boot loop

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox

I tried to run RemixOS inside VirtualBox on Ubuntu, but RemixOS runs in an endless boot loop. It's the problem mentioned [here](http://support.jide.com/hc/en-us/articles/215648958-What-if-my-PC-is-stuck-at-the-flashing-display-of-Remix-OS-and-cannot-proceed-to-setup-) too.
These are my settings:

[image: RemixOS]

Any ideas what could cause these endless boot loop?